# Can't seem to figure out how to redirect to a .xhtml using primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, xhtml

I have a index.xhtml file in WebContent folder which is my main page. There I can send some data to a controller which will then redirect to an list.xhtml file located in WEB-INF/jsf/. list.xhtml is in WEB-INF/jsf/ so it couldn't be accessed without sending the data from the index page.

Anyway the redirect from index.xhtml to list.xhtml works perfectly ( `<p:commandButton />` with an action to a controller ). The problem is navigating back from list.xhtml to index.xhtml. No matter what I do it doesn't seem to work.

So far I've tried:

`<h:button value="Go Back" outcome="index.xhtml" />` - button is greyed out with the message `This button is disabled because a navigation case could not be matched`. Assuming that's because it's searching for index.xhtml in WEB-INF/jsf/

`<h:button value="Go Back" outcome="../../index.xhtml" />` - same result as above

`<p:commandButton value="Go Back" action="#{listController.goBack}" />` and `action="#{goBackController.goBack}"` - with goBack() method returning the same thing that was in outcome values in previous examples

If anyone could push me in the right direction that'd be much appreciated.

Also I am aware that webpages shouldn't really be in WEB-INF but I don't know how else to hide the list.xhtml page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 things about `outcome` that you need to know:

1. You cannot use a full page name with `.xhtml` as a value for `outcome`. For example, if the page name is `Example.xhtml`, the proper way is `outcome="Example"`.
2. Suppose at the moment you're at this page `http://yourdomain.com/app/folder/Page1.xhtml`, if you click on a button with `outcome="Page2"`, you will arrive at `http://yourdomain.com/app/folder/Page2.xhtml`. You cannot use `../` in the `outcome` to navigate to the parent folder.

Try this:

```
<p:button value="Go back" href="../../index.xhtml" />
```

If it doesn't work, put an absolute path in the `href` should do the job.

Comment: You can also add navigation rule in faces-config as:         `<navigation-rule>
   <from-view-id>WEB-INF/jsf/list.xhtml</from-view-id>
   <navigation-case>
     <from-outcome>Index</from-outcome>
      <to-view-id>/index.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>              
</navigation-rule>`

Comment: Thanks! `<p:button value="Go Back" href="index.xhtml" />` worked.